# Is there any way to select multiple photos in a Flickr Album?

Tags: flickr

Is there any way to select multiple photos in a Flickr Album?  I have 1 album with three different cameras, so they are very out of order.  I want to select 3-6 at a time and move them to another part of an 800 photo album.

Select click does not work and it deletes the photo.